# Sql query for specific data

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have an Archive Table. The columns are PK, Users and Logdatetime. When Users log in the system i am writing to archive table the user and datetime. A user can login more than one in one day.

The data in Logdatetime is like '2010-03-16 00:00:00.000'

I need to query all users FIRST Login time in one day and get the user with the datetime like:
user1 '2010-03-16 03:21:00.000'
user2 '2010-03-16 04:11:00.000'

It does not matter the users order.
I tried too many way but couldnt find a way. The only solution i found is the query for all users one by one. But it will take time. Any idea how to do this with a one query or more efficent way?

PS: I am using MS SQL Server 2005

Comment: Yes, just browse these answers, they are all duplicates of your question (swap max for min where appropriate): [tag:greatest-n-per-group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group)

Comment: There was a question asked only a few minutes ago which should give you the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089777/how-to-select-top-record-of-same-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want the users very first login or the just first of a specific day?

This example query might lead you in the right direction;

```
SELECT [User], MIN(LogDateTime) AS FirstLogin FROM [Archive Table] GROUP BY [User]
```